# Two variable in one for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, fastq

I have a directory and inside I have two file types :  *.sai and *fastq and I vant to use both variable in one shell for loop:

```
for j in *sai *fastq

 do bwa samse $j $j > ${j%.sai}.sam 

done;
```

after command `do` I want to load corresponding *.sai and *.fastq data in to the program (bwa samse). Could you help me please with syntax?

EXAMPLE:

in one directory is `xx.fast xx.sai yy.fastq yy.sai` and program bwa samse need to process in one time two corresponding files - `bwa samse xx.fastq xx.sai...`

Many thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Does the two files (at a time) have the same starting name before sai & fastq ?

Comment: yes they have the same name before extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this with bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
for j in .*sai; do  
    [[ -s ${j%.sai}.fastq ]] &&
        bwa samse "$j" "${j%.sai}.fastq" > "${j%.sai}.sam"     
done
```

and please, stop killing kitties with parsing `ls` output. (not for you Incorigible)

Comment: What does the lonesome `$j%` do?  Is that a typo?
Also, I would recommend checking that the corresponding `.fastq` file exists, just for sanity's sake.

Comment: @sputnick Yeah it works perfect - thank you so much - I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `ls` to feed the loop. Use **brace expansion** to only include `*.sai` and `*.fastq` files in your loop:

```
for j in ./*.{sai,fastq}
do
    ## do what you need to the *.sai & *.fastq files 
done
```

You can also provide a path variable:

```
mypath=/path/to/files
for j in "${mypath}"/*.{sai,fastq}
(snip)
```

**NOTE:** No clue what `bwa samse $j $j > ${j%\.*}.sam` does. Explain how you need to process the files and I can help further..

If there is a 1-to-1 relationship (matching .sai and .fastq files), then just:

```
for j in ./*.sai
do
    fname="${j%.*}"   # remove the extension ($fname is filename w/o ext)
    ## do what you need to the *.sai & *.fastq files 
    #  bwa samse "${fname}.sai" "${fname}.fastq" whatever else
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel bwa samse ref.fasta {} {.}.fastq '>' {.}.sam  ::: *.sai
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 0):

(editted to reflect the comments--using `ls` to list filenames isn't necessary)

To strip the file extension you'll need to use `${j%\.*}`, which will retain all characters before the last `.`

```
for j in *.sai *.fastq
do
    bwa samse $j $j > ${j%\.*}.sam 
done;
```

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this. `for j in *.sai *.fastq` is correct.

Comment: @eigenchris Thank you for comment. Indirectory I have for example xx.fast xx.sai yy.fastq yy.sai and program bwa samse need to process in one time two corresponding files - bwa samse xx.fastq xx.sai... Right now it gave me bwa samse xx.fastq xx.fastq (two times the same file). I hope it is clear :-)

Comment: Need more quotes, see <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes>, <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments> and <http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words>.